# Why does Future Perfect Tense "sound" as though it didn't happen?

Tags: phrase-meaning, future, future-perfect

Consider these sentences:

> They *will* walk before breakfast.
>   They *will have* walked before breakfast.

The first sentence expresses an action that will end before another action occurs *in the future*. No issues with that.

The second sentence must also express the same information. But somehow it seems *to me* that it conveys a *past action that didn't happen*/*failed to happen*. I know this is incorrect, but I'd like to know more about why this particular tense is throwing me off. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The second sentence may mean different things depending on contex, because *will* can be used not only to express future, but also habit or strong probability in a conjecture. Perhaps that's what was nibbling on your brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...it seems to me that it conveys a past action that didn't happen/failed to happen.

Well, that's wrong. The *will* establishes that is not the case.

> I know this is incorrect...

Well, good.

> ...but I'd like to know more about why this particular tense is throwing me off.

No one else can really answer why you're making a particular mistake.

My best guess would be that it's a mix of **a)** no one using the future perfect tense very often and **b)** your having misunderstood the future tense. It's the verb in the *second* sentence that specifically expresses an action that will have ended before another action in the future. The verb in the *first* sentence merely expresses the action will occur sometime in the future.

Of course, like in Chinese, you can get the same point across without [conjugating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation) the verb by using an appropriate adverb to lock it in to the appropriate place in time. That is, in fact, *why* [no one really uses the future perfect](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+will+do+it%2CI+will+have+done+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) [all that often in English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+will+do+it+by%2CI+will+have+done+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

**Edit**: [See here for a few cases where some people use it to describe the past](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/will-have-or-would-have). It needs to be in a particular context, though, comparing the other action to something occurring in the present: "Don't call. It's 9 o'clock. She will have already gone to bed by now." Even there, I'd say it's more slipshod than formally correct, but it is an accepted usage.

Comment: Ah "will" establishes it's not a past action. I see... Thank you :)

Comment: I think I was getting tripped because I was mixing up Future Perfect with other forms like : 1)  She could have passed the exam.  2) He should have started early.

Comment: @rsadhvika ...or even closer to home, *would have...*, but all of those are different from the future perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The modal *will* has different functions. In the first sentence plain *will* is used to give information or make a prediction about the future.

The *will have* construction in the second sentence, out of context, is ambiguous. Again, it can be used to predict the future - specifically about will have happened before another future event. For example:

> I will have finished cutting the grass before my wife gets home.

Or in the current case, what they will have done before another future event (breakfast).

But *will have* can also used to make a supposition about or express the likeliness of a past event. For example, in the following contrived context.

> - Why were they so tired yesterday evening?
> - They will have walked before breakfast.

In other words, you are right that *will have walked* can refer to a past event. But it is not one that failed to happen. It is the speaker's assessment of what probably happened.

Comment: In the last example, you'd usually say "they (probably/likely/&c.) walked before breakfast". Even if you were using the future perfect, you'd use its past form "would have". You could use "will've" colloquially but technically incorrectly.

Comment: Some people [*do* use it to talk about the past](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/will-have-or-would-have), but only in relation to the present and not to other past events.

Comment: "Will", like other modals, has an epistemic meaning  (expressing conclusions or belief) as well as a deontic one (expressing necessity or actuality). That is another reason why it is a nonsense to refer to  "will go" etc as a "tense". It is a modal expression (like "can go" and "should go"), one of whose meanings is futurity.

Comment: +1 for being the first to remind us that will + have +PP can be used to express meaning in the past. I think it's quite rare though

Comment: @Ily. Certainly the second function of the future perfect, as exemplified above, is rare. But you will hear it in utterances such as: _They will have arrived home by now._ I'm not sure you can call it _technically incorrect_.